# Converting Base10 integer to Base64 representation in Python

Tags: python, binary, base64, byte

So this is my code, which throws a MemoryError at line 2 with no other details.

```
import base64
b = bytes(2108292477256562115)
print(base64.urlsafe_b64encode(b))
```

Comment: `b = b'2108292477256562115'` or `b = str(n).encode()`.

Answer (score 1):

`bytes(2108292477256562115)` is a byte string with length 2108292477256562115. If you want to convert that integer to a minimal number of bytes, you need to get the number of bytes required to represent it first:

```
n = 2108292477256562115
byte_length = (n.bit_length() + 7) // 8
```

then convert:

```
n.to_bytes(byte_length, 'big')
```